# Is it possible to rollback an edit so that your name is not shown in the edit by column?

Tags: discussion, support

I did a rollback on the edit. But it still shows that the question is edited by me. Is it possible to remove that?

Comment: No. You rolled back so you did something to the revision history.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You were the last person to action the post and therefore your name is associated with that action's timestamp.

Comment: the post was looking like B. Then someone decided to make it look like A..... the "edited by" should highlight who was the last person to make an edit. Whether it was YOUR text or not, YOU chose that it should look like B. Why shouldn't it display you?

Comment: Why would removal be useful? If you go on a vandalising spree rolling back lots of posts willy nilly we'll want to know what you did!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

A roll-back is just another revision in the revision history. And revisions are attributed to a user. You can see those both in the [revisions on a post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28597239/revisions) or in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475228/pritam-banerjee?tab=activity&sort=revisions) on your profile.

This transparency exists so we can ask you: *Why did you remove the tag* in case someone wonders as they might want to add the same tag again. If the revisions are anonymous or redacted you have to either flag for a moderator or contact the team.

There does exist an option to remove a revision but that is only used in extreme cases where keeping the revision around would be harmful. That does require involvement of an employee so only use it when warranted.